# Python extraction of multiple common prefix with minimum length of 4 that will match all numbers in the cell

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = {
'number': ['9020442,9028581132,9503312,78', '3553023,3553024,3553025,355,858000'],
'operator': ['zone 1', 'zone 2']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I have this data and I need to split the numbers and get a list of common prefix with a minimum length of 4. Expected output is a dataframe like this

```
             number operator
0  9020,9028,9503,78  zone 1
1      3553,355,8580  zone 2
```

Comment: So ordering is not important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to get the first 4 characters of each number, with a `set` to keep unique values:

```
df['number'] = [','.join(set(x[:4] for x in  s.split(',')))
                for s in df['number']]
```

Or with a regex:

```
import re

df['number'] = [','.join(set(re.findall(r'\b(\d{1,4})', s)))
                for s in df['number']]
```

Output:

```
              number operator
0  9020,78,9503,9028   zone 1
1      3553,8580,355   zone 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `dict.fromkeys` trick for unique splitted values in original order in lambda function:

```
f = lambda x: ','.join(dict.fromkeys(y[:4] for y in x.split(',')))
df['number'] = df['number'].apply(f)
```

or with list comprehension:

```
df['number'] = [','.join(dict.fromkeys(y[:4] for y in x.split(','))) for x in df['number']]
print (df)
              number operator
0  9020,9028,9503,78   zone 1
1      3553,355,8580   zone 2
```

If order is not important use `set`s:

```
f = lambda x: ','.join(set(y[:4] for y in x.split(',')))
df['number'] = df['number'].apply(f)
```

---

```
df['number'] = [','.join(set(y[:4] for y in x.split(','))) for x in df['number']]

print (df)
              number operator
0  9028,78,9020,9503   zone 1
1      355,3553,8580   zone 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution :

```
df["number"] = (
    df["number"].str.findall(r"(\d{1,4})\d*")
        .apply(lambda x: ",".join(dict.fromkeys(x)))
)
```

> Demo : [[*Regex101*](https://regex101.com/r/GHGXku/2)]

Output :

```
print(df)

              number operator
0  9020,9028,9503,78   zone 1
1      3553,355,8580   zone 2
```

Comment: You don't really need the `(?=,|$)` because `\d{1,4}` will always match before the greedy `\d*` there is no need to match the end :)

Comment: I knew there was something superfluous with my pattern (*pretty much as usual haha*). Thanks mozway ;)